# Core data multithreading and nested contexts

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have just began learning core data programming. I tried to make an example in which there is a table view that displays a list of persons (properties : first name, last name). The table view relies on an NSFetchResultController to display the list of persons.

I followed the nested contexts pattern as follows :

Root Context (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) <---> Main Context (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) <---> Children Contexts (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType).

The children contexts are used to perform huge insertion/fetch (with perormBlock: method).
When i try to perform a huge insertion (about 5000 rows), save the child context then the main context then the root context, i see that my UI is blocked until the save is finished.

Could any one please tell me what is the best solution to adopt in order to make a performant application ? Could anyone please provide me a nice simple code that show how to make huge fetch/insertion in background without blocking the UI?

```
    [_indicator startAnimating];

NSManagedObjectContext *aContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
aContext.parentContext = [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] mainManagedObjectContext];

[aContext performBlock:^{

    NSError *error;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        FootBallCoach *backgroundCoach = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"FootBallCoach" inManagedObjectContext:aContext];

        backgroundCoach.firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"José %i",i];
        backgroundCoach.lastName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Morinho %i",i];
        backgroundCoach.cin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];

        if (i % 50 == 0)
        {
            [aContext save:&error];

            [aContext reset];
        }
    }

    [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMainContext];
    [[SDCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveRootContext];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [_indicator stopAnimating];

        [self refreshCoaches:nil];
    });

}];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do "huge" imports.
Each time a write operation is done to the store, the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is locking the store for any other kind of operations. So, if your UI is trying to fetch data during that time, it will be blocked.

Segment your saves to 100~200 objects (depending on object size and complexity).
The segmentation really depend on your object graph structure, a pseudocode would be:

**Edit:** I've edited the code to reflect a correction to your save process.
Your save to the store (the actual file) should also be segmented, otherwise you still end-up with a "huge" save operation.

```
for ( i = 0; i < LARGE_N; i += BATCHSIZE)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        batchInfo = importInfos[i : MIN(i+BATCHSIZE-1,LARGE_N-1]; //array of the batch
        //use existing objects or create new ones if needed
        //use batch fetching to reduce existing items find time
        batchInfo = createOrReuseItemsForBatchInfo(batchInfo);
        //you can also practice weeding:
        //  create all items as newly inserted
        //  after batch insertion completed, find existing items, 
        //     replace them with the newly inserted and delete the duplicated inserted objects.
        //save all the way to the store
        NSManagedObjectContext* ctx = context;
        __block BOOL saveSuccessful = YES;
        while(ctx && saveSuccessful) {
            [ctx performBlockAndWait:^{
                saveSuccessful = [ctx save:&error]
            }];
            ctx = ctx.parentContext;
        }
        //handle unsuccessful save
        [context  reset];
        //You can discard processed objects from importInfos array if you like
    }
}
```

Comment: Well right now i am running a for loop and saving each time i insert 100 items. Do you confirm that the nested contexts approach is the best one to follow ?

Comment: When first my data base is empty, it works fine. But when i have about 20 000 items and i try to insert 5000 new ones, the UI is blocked.

Comment: If you save 100 items, and the UI is still blocked try reducing the batch size. The nested context architecture is good for some things (mostly small imports and simple store operations from my experience).  If you need maximal concurrency, you could use multi-coordinator environment (but then you will need to merge changes to your main context which is a story on its own).

Comment: a 5K items insertion will always be slow as the write operation block the file on the OS level. as I said, use segmented import (its better to spend more time on a BG thread and perform read operations, then block the UI too often and for long periods).

Comment: I have just tried the multi-coordinator environment approach and i have the same results. Each every new insert operation (5000 items) i create a separate context the with the performBlock: method i save each time i insert 100 items. My tableView (based on NSFetchResultController) is still blocking.

Comment: reduce the batch size. even in a multi-coordinator environment, the OS will lock the file on each write operation. you can also add a small delay before you save in the BG context. Please add the stack architectures you tried and the results you got from saving.

Comment: I edited my question. I have added the code that adds new items to my data base. This code implements the nested contexts approach.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You should save your segment up to the store, and not only one level up. otherwise you end up with a "huge" save operation that will block the UI.